# java 1.4 projects compatible with Java 7?

Tags: java

Is the java 1.4 projects compatible with Java 7?

any known issue from anybody.
In my case, when I use a class which was compiled using 1.4 (javap -verbose, major version:48) with Java6 it works fine. 
But the same class with Java 7 code resulting in null pointer

any ideas appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace please? There are inconsistencies between java 1.6 and java 1.7, but we've got no idea what your problem is if you don't give us a clue to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously Sun, and now Oracle, have always been extremely careful to keep Java upwards compatible, which means that Java programs written for and compiled on older versions should work without modification on newer versions of Java (with minor exceptions).

However, it is possible for people to write programs that aren't compatible - for example if your program directly uses classes in a `sun.*` or `com.sun.*` package, it is possible that it will not work anymore on a newer version of Java (or on a JVM implementation other than Oracle's).

[Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) contains details on the compatibility of Java 7 with older releases.

Without any more specific information about your program, it's impossible to tell you exactly why it doesn't work properly on Java 7.

Comment: thanks Jasper...the java 1.4 class is a closed source for me i.e i got it from a vendor. Am getting a nullpointerexception on their code...How do i ensure its a compatiblity issue

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? That might contain some information about where exactly it goes wrong. Ask the vendor if their software is compatible with Java 7, or ask them to check and solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jasper... i asked my vendor actually